# Bootstrap 4 badge overlay top-left, and stay on navbar link even on collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add notification badge to a nav link, and I have 2 problems:

1) I can't make it be over the image top-left.

2) When the navbar is collapsed, the badge goes all the way to the left:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
   Logo
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">         
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a id="chats_link" class="nav-link" href="/group_chats.php" style="margin-right:15px;color:white;">                        
                        <img title="Chats" src="/resources/chat_navbar.png" alt="Chats" width="25" height="25" style="z-index:10;">
                        <span class="badge badge-primary" style="z-index:15;float:left;margin-bottom:-10px;left:5px; top:-10px;position:relative;">9</span>)    
                    </a>
                </li> 
           </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would this be what you are looking for? (added left: -20px; to the style of the badge, removed some other stuff)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
   Logo
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">         
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-right:15px;color:white;">                        
                        <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e71/frog-1371919.jpg" alt="image" width="35" height="35" style="z-index:10;">
                        <span class="badge badge-primary" style="z-index:15;position:relative; left: -40px; top:-10px"">9</span>)    
                    </a>
                </li> 
           </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the fiddle, and some of the post: You're solution is nearly correct but I also want it to be at the top.
At the new fiddle, you can see where I want it (When navbar is not collapsed - at the top-left, not right, my mistake) And when it's collapsed you can see that it goes all the way to the left instead of staying on the picture
I'd be glad if you can show the 2 versions: the badge top-right and top-left (And stay there on collapse)

Comment: I edited the fiddle again with your last suggestion (except that instead of -40px I used 5px). You can see it looks OK when navbar is on full screen, but when it's collapsed, it's going all the way to the left instead of staying on the image

Comment: Does it really nee the "float:left;margin-bottom:-10px;"? I think it will work ok without this.

Comment: Ok You're right! It's working without the float, thank you :)